# Storyboard in DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `ToggleButton` that open a popup, and have a `ItemsControl` in `Popup`.

I want to hide popup when click on items in items control.

```
<ToggleButton Content="?????" x:Name="LeaveButton" Style="{StaticResource ToggleButtonImageStyle}" Padding="13"/>
<Popup 
   KeyDown="UIElement_OnKeyDown" 
   Opened="SubMenuPopup_OnOpened" 
   IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=LeaveButton}" 
   StaysOpen="False" 
   x:Name="LeavePopup" 
   AllowsTransparency="True" 
   PopupAnimation="Fade" 
   PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=LeaveButton}" 
   Placement="Right">
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="15">
      <Polygon Points="15 15,0 30,15 45" Fill="{DynamicResource HeaderBackgroundBrush}" />
      <StackPanel  Width="250">
         <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding WorkshopList}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                  <Button 
                     Content="{Binding Name}"
                     Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.LeaveCommand}" 
                     CommandParameter="{Binding Id}" 
                     Style="{StaticResource ButtonImageTextStyle}" 
                     Padding="20">
                     <Button.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click">
                           <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HideLeavePopup}" />
                        </EventTrigger>
                     </Button.Triggers>
                  </Button>
               </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         </ItemsControl>
      </StackPanel>
   </StackPanel>
</Popup>
```

and set a story for this.

```
<Storyboard x:Key="HideLeavePopup" Storyboard.TargetName="LeaveButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
   <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
      <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1" Value="False" />
   </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

but when I use this, I get following error

> LeaveButton name can not be found in the name scope of type 'System.Windows.Control.Button'

Comment: Aside from resolving the error you're getting, I think that your approach is not a good one (I've found that out myself not long ago). The problem with property animation is that it doesn't actually set the property value, but rather overrides the effective value. As a result two scenarios are possible: if animation's `FillBehavior` is set to `HoldEnd`, the animation will prevent the popup from reopening (the `IsOpen` effective value will be held `false`), else (if set to `Stop`) the effective `IsOpen` value will revert back to `true`, causing the popup to reopen once the animation is over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends where `Storyboard` is defined so I'll assume it's in `Window.Resources` or something alike. You use `TargetName` as *LeaveButton* and `TargetProperty` as *IsOpen*. You want either *LeaveButton* and *IsChecked* or *LeavePopup* and *IsOpen*. Also try changing `TargetName` to `Target` and use binding:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="HideLeavePopup" 
            Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName=LeaveButton}"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsChecked">
    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1" Value="False" />
    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: Thanks, i use this but get erro again.

Comment: What error? Same as in your question? Where is storyboard defined?

Comment: Thanks a lot ... it is ok :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27714597/name-cannot-be-found-in-the-name-scope-of-system-windows-controls-button)

Inside of your storyboard, Instead of

```
Storyboard.TargetName="LeaveButton"
```

use

```
Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName=LeaveButton}"
```

Comment: Thanks, But i get error: IsChecked:true name can not be fount in the name of scope

Comment: Another answer made it clear. It should be IsOpen property and not IsChecked.